# Log4j.xml smtpappender emailthrottle

Tags: log4j, smtpappender

I have a log4J.xml SMTPAppender configuration as follows:

```
  <appender name="MAIL" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
    <param name="EvaluatorClass" value="fi.reaktor.log4j.emailthrottle.ErrorEmailThrottle"/>
    <param name="BufferSize" value="512"/>
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="xxxx"/>
    <param name="SMTPPort" value="25"/>
    <param name="From" value="xxxx"/>
    <param name="To" value="xxx"/>
    <param name="Subject" value="xxx"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] [%c{1}: %M] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I use an EvaluatorClass that I was advised on the link: https://github.com/reaktor/log4j-email-throttle

On the page, it was marked that you can change the default configuration in a log4j.properties file:

```
  fi.reaktor.log4j.emailthrottle.throttleIfUnderSecs=60
  fi.reaktor.log4j.emailthrottle.emailIntervalInSecs=900
  fi.reaktor.log4j.emailthrottle.normalAfterSecs=3600
```

Unfortunately, I do not see how to apply it in my Log4j.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

The page you refer to says:

> You can change default values by setting these System properties
>   So you can't put those settings in log4j config file.

You either need to set those properties on the command line where you start jvm, with "-D" flag:

> java -Dfi.reaktor.log4j.emailthrottle.throttleIfUnderSecs=60 \
>     -Dfi.reaktor.log4j.emailthrottle.emailIntervalInSecs=900 \
>     -Dfi.reaktor.log4j.emailthrottle.normalAfterSecs=3600

or set it from your code programmatically:

```
System.setProperty("fi.reaktor.log4j.emailthrottle.throttleIfUnderSecs", "60");
System.setProperty("fi.reaktor.log4j.emailthrottle.emailIntervalInSecs", "900");
System.setProperty("fi.reaktor.log4j.emailthrottle.normalAfterSecs", "3600");
```